# Create a Git repo with two independently updatable repos

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I want to create a custom project skeleton for future projects using both the HTML5 Boilerplate repo and the HTML5BP Ant Build Script repo.

I want my directory structure as follows

```
/public       #this is where my build script will build to
/source       #this contains the html5bp files
     /build   #this contains the build script files
```

I want to be able to modify the build script repo to work how I want it to. I also want to be able to fetch updates from the original repo (the only way I can think of doing this is to fork the build script (and add an upstream remote) and then include that as a submodule - will this work?).

However I am not sure how to get the HTML5BP repo in a state where it is inside the /source folder and in a state where I can fetch new updates from the original repo and make my own modifications to set it up as I want it for my future projects.

If I fork it and then move all its files into a /source directory, would an upstream remote know where to look in order to fetch new updates?

I've tried messing about with this and haven't really got anywhere yet, I'm also pretty new to Git.

Comment: It sounds like you could play with git submodule

Answer (score 0):

> the only way I can think of doing this is to fork the build script (and add an upstream remote) and then include that as a submodule - will this work?

Yes, as a submodule of `html5bp` repo

> I am not sure how to get the `HTML5BP` repo in a state where it is inside the `/source` folder

Why not clone the `html5bp` repo under the root directory `source`?

Comment: if I do a straight 'clone' will I be able to fetch updates from the original html5bp repo as well as modify and commit files to my own repo?

Comment: @DGoomany If you clone from the original `html5bp` itself, then yes, you will fetch from that repo, since it would be declare as a remote (type `git remote -v show` inside `source/` in order to see it). But the idea remains to do a `git clone https://url/original/html5bp source` in order to clone it directly within the `source` directory.